# Why is a directory named "res" auto generated in Android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Android Studio generates a "res" folder:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By Default, the initial Android Studio project has a default icon in the mip-map folder. They're customized for different screen resolutions when added.

Comment: I think that is a inbuild u know

Comment: The "mipmap" folder is inside the regular "res" folder. OP is asking about the generated "res" folder as indicated in the screenshot, six entries below the "mipmap" folder.

Answer (score -1):

When you create new project, Android Studio create **res** folder by default to store some resource.

Comment: What resources?  Why does it need to store them?